# Patent WO 2014122535 A2 (US 14/172,685): User Interface, prior art exists

Tags: prior-art, software, user-interface, wo-2014122535

I studied this patent (pending) and it seems obvious to me that prior art apply on:

**System for organizing and displaying information on a display device 
[WO2014122535A2](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140223313?hl=fr&dq=dizmo&ei=fTt6VL_MK_HksASKvYLYBQ&cl=fr)

[US20140223313](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140223313?hl=fr&dq=dizmo&ei=fTt6VL_MK_HksASKvYLYBQ&cl=fr)**

**Application number US 14/172,685**

(PCT) 
Pub. No.:       WO/2014/122535      International Application No.:      PCT/IB2014/000684
Publication Date:   14.08.2014  International Filing Date:  04.02.2014

I'm very knowledgeable in User interface paradigms, I'm coauthor of several patents in UI/UX, and I see no innovation here.

This patent is about user interface: grouping, docking and transforming windows (move, rotate, scale) together by layering system.

I know at least some prior art that I would like to see confirmed and submitted to Examiner before this becomes an issued Patent:

**Publication in 1995: [Directness and Liveness in the Morphic User Interface Construction Environment](http://web.media.mit.edu/~jmaloney/papers/DirectnessAndLivenessInMorphic.pdf)
John H. Maloney Randall B. Smith
Apple Computer, Inc**

This paper explain morphic UI, and way to organize and transform user interface in a hierarchical manner, exactly as "layering" does in the patent.
Those techniques have been implemented with graphical objects and windows in the software **Smalltalk Squeak before 2009.**
**http://www.squeak.org/
Books, documentation and [videos](https://www.youtube.com/user/sparaig?feature=watch) exist on Squeak for many years.**

In 2000, from the same author:
[An Introduction to Morphic: The Squeak User Interface Framework
John Maloney Walt Disney Imagineering](http://coweb.cc.gatech.edu/squeakbook/uploads/morphic2.pdf)

Other prior art may be found, but this one should be sufficient to oppose to the main claims. 
Zooming and unzooming layers/Windows is so well known in CAD and UI systems that it cannot justify innovation even by juxtaposition.

Let me know if you think this pertinent.